# Can a non-retina iMac with i7 3.5 Ghz and GTX775M handle three displays?

Tags: imac, hardware, thunderbolt-display, cinema-display

I am thinking about getting a used ***non-retina*** iMac with these specs:

```
Core i7 3,5 GHz
32GB RAM
1TB SSD
GTX 775M
```

Since I own two Apple 27" Displays I'd like to hook these up via Thunderbolt/MDP.

My question is: Can the iMac handle all the 3 displays (including the built-in one) or will I have UI lag/stutter? Will the iMac get hot? How would the fan noise be with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referencing a 27" Late 2013 iMac because there is no 21" iMac that has that specific CPU frequency.

You can have up to two external displays connected via **Thunderbolt**  according to the specs posted on [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i7-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-late-2013-specs.html)

[image]

I have used 30" and 43" displays with my iMac and there has been zero lag.  I also only have SSDs (no hard drives) so I have had zero issues with heat, even with multiple displays.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps:

- Go to the Apple Menu (top-left hand corner)
- Click `About this Mac`
- Check your graphics card,

What does it tell you it can handle?